# Como instalo ubuntu en una Pc que tiene lubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

I want to install Ubuntu on my computer which has Lubuntu. How can I remove Lubuntu and install Ubuntu. Thanks.

Hola la verdad soy nuevo utilizando linux y no se como hacerlo pues yo quiero instalar ubuntu en mi ordenador pero tengo instalado el lubuntu como le puedo hacer para eliminar lubuntu y poner ubuntu bueno espero y me puedan responder Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first install the `ubuntu-desktop` package from the Software Center. This will install everything related to Ubuntu. Afterwards, logout and then, on the login window (Where you type your user/password) select Ubuntu.

After logging in Ubuntu you can proceed to remove the `lubuntu-desktop` package and anything related to Lubuntu. Know that leaving it there won't affect performance. You will be only using a bit more space.